# Getting notified when a .NET object is destroyed?

Tags: c#, destructor, idisposable

I would like to know if it is possible to execute some C# code when an object is getting destroyed?

I tried to use `IDiposable`, but my `Dispose` method is not getting called.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you need to more actively control the lifetime of the object's resources?  Is this just for diagnostics?  Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx on C# destructors?

Comment: read about OOP, ctors, destructors

Comment: You can have finalizer (closest thing to the question, but unlikely what you want)... You can't get notified when `myObj = null` get called... Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You should think carefully about your need for a Finalizer.. and what you put in it.

Comment: You should not depend on desctructors. You should implement IDisposable and call Dispose when you are done with your object.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this through `Garbage Collection Notification`, which allow you to sense and respond when a full garbage collection is approaching and when the full `garbage collection has completed`.

[Garbage Collection Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If an object creates an instance of a type with a finalizer, keeps a reference to that instance, and does not expose that reference to anyone, then when the object holding the only reference becomes eligible for collection, the finalizer of that latter object will be enqueued to run at the next opportunity.  Note that the garbage-collector does not run finalizers; it merely adds finalizable objects to a list of things whose finalizers should run as soon as practical.  No objects which is on that list, nor any other object to which it holds a direct or indirect strong reference, will be eligible for collection until it ceases to be on that list.  If your finalizable object does not hold a reference to the object that holds the reference to it, and if that other object doesn't have a finalizer of its own, that object will be cease to exist once no references exist to it; by the time the finalizer of the latter object runs, the former object won't exist anymore.